# Kafka + Storm - satisfying dependencies

Tags: java, scala, apache-storm

I'm attempting to deploy my first topology to a storm cluster as part of an assessment for my company. The topology is just to get values from **kafka** and put them into **cassandra** and **redis**.

After copying over scads of .jar files to try to satisfy the various dependencies I've run into a issue where **storm** claims a dependency is missing but the startup class list in the logs shows the class as available.

Here's the exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
>           at kafka.utils.Pool.(Pool.scala:28) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
>           at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$.
>   ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
>           at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$.(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
>           at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.(SimpleConsumer.scala:39) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
>           at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.(SimpleConsumer.scala:34) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
>           at storm.kafka.DynamicPartitionConnections.register(DynamicPartitionConnections.java:60) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
>           at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.(PartitionManager.java:64) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
>           at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
>           at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
>           at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:135) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
>           at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4654$fn__4669$fn__4698.invoke(executor.clj:565) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
>           at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__458.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
>           at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

When I look at the startup info for the supervisor thread I see this:

> 2015-06-07T07:55:19.941-0700 o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.class.path=  ... /usr/local/src/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/scala-library-2.11.6.jar: ...

When I open this file I see this entry:

> -rwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Mar 18  2014 scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.class

So something else is amiss. What step(s) have I missed here?

NOTE: similar issues from org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFactory..

Comment: I believe this is something related to the scala version u are using. Seems that the kafka you are using is compiled with scala 2.10 and probably you have 2.11 installed .. just a thought but it might worth looking at

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka version specifies which Scala version it is built against.

> Scala 2.10  - kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1.tgz (asc, md5)
>
> Scala 2.11  - kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1.tgz (asc, md5)

I made the mistake of using Scala 2.10 with kafka 2.11.
I was able to resolve this by correcting my maven dependancies to the correct scala and kafka combination.

Answer (score 0):

> Release Notes Source download: [kafka-0.11.0.1-src.tgz](https://github.com/apache/kafka/archive/0.11.0.1.tar.gz) (asc, md5)

```
Binary downloads: Scala 2.11  - kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1.tgz (asc, md5)
Scala 2.12  - kafka_2.12-0.11.0.1.tgz (asc, md5) We build for multiple
```

This only matters if you are using Scala and you want a version built for the same Scala version you use. Otherwise any version should work (2.11 is recommended).